# after login display client first name in the top of my header page in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i have registration page after user register goes to login page,i want to display a user first name in the top pf my header page when we click username i want a dropdown logout after click on logout user shuold be logout..

```
here is my controller code:

public function login()
 {
       $data['error'] ="Invalid Login";
       $this->load->view('auth/header');
           if($this->input->post())
             {
              $user = $this->UserModel->login($this->input->post());
               if(count($user)>0)
                    {
                     $array = array(
                             'client_id' => $user['client_id'],
                             'first_name' => $user['first_name'],
                             'client_type_id'=>$user['client_type_id'],
                             'email' => $user['email'],
                             'password' => $user['password'],
                 );
                $this->session->set_userdata('userdata',$array);

    if($user['client_id'] == $user['client_id'])
    {
        redirect(base_url('dashboard/dashboard'));
    } 
}
else
{
 $data["error_message"]="Invalid User Name and Password combination";
}
```

logout

```
function logout()
{
    $this->session->unset_userdata(userdata);
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
  redirect('Auth/login','refresh');
}
```

view:

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="dropdown" class="right_color">
            <?php
             echo $this->session->userdata('userdata');
            ?>
            <!-- <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/admin.jpg" alt="admin-pic">-->
            </a>
```

Logout

Comment: after login i got an error in header page array to string conversation

Comment: learn [basic debugging](http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/basic-debugging/) in PHP

Comment: ok can you please tell me  why this error occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current session is in a nested array format

```
array(userdata=>array(your session))
```

in your controller replace your session set code

to this

```
$this->session->set_userdata($array);
```

and in your view

```
echo $this->session->userdata('first_name');
```

Comment: if your using CI3 you can directly use $this->session->first_name;

Comment: thank you but after i logout ,if i click on back button username displays

Comment: try this `<?= ($this->session->first_name)? $this->session->first_name : "" ?>`        this is a short hand if stament

Comment: thank you its working but i have another problem i put code as when user directly open dashboard through URL redirect to login,but its not working can you please help me how to do this

Comment: function __Construct()
 {
  parent::__Construct ();
  
  if(! isset($this->session->userdata['userinfo']))
       {
   redirect(base_url('../fms/login'));
         //exit;
       }

Comment: my dashboard constructor

Comment: im assuming its rendering through cache....casue im currently working on a ci project an my login is getting validated

Comment: can you please explain in code how to do that one if u have any idea?

Comment: Is your login and dashboard functions in the same controller?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting array of data in session. You are trying to print array of data. It will throw array to string conversion error. Change this following and try :-

For creating session:-

```
 $this->session->set_userdata($array);
```

Now you print:-

```
<?php
    echo $this->session->userdata('client_id');
    echo $this->session->userdata('first_name');
    echo $this->session->userdata('email'); 
?>
```

For more about **Session** refer this link https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html